# What is an auto-associator?

Tags: neural-networks, math, hebbian-learning

What is an auto-associator, and how does it work? How can we design an auto-associator for a given pattern? I couldn't find a clear explanation for this anywhere on the internet.

Here's an example of a pattern.

[image: example pattern]

Comment: Hi and welcome to AI SE! Where did you hear of this term "auto-associator"? In which context? Are you referring to "auto-associative memory"? Please, edit your post to explain this.

Comment: Hi, I came across this term when trying to solve a problem in neural networks. I came across auto-associative memory also. But couldn't find what is meant exactly by an auto associator. so I asked here. :) look forward to some help.

Comment: Can you please provide a link to the source where you read the term "auto-associator"?